# Weird SVG mask behaviour on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, mask

I encountered weird behavior with what I thought was a really simple SVG mask:

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400">
      <rect x="0" y="100" width="400" height="100" fill="#FFF"></rect>    
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#mask)">
    <rect fill="#BBB" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400"></rect>    
  </g>
</svg>
```

On Chrome it renders as 3 gray rectangles (two of which reacts to scroll), while I believe it should be only one rectangle (firefox and edge renders it so)

[corresponding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndEDq.jpg) (left: edge/firefox | right: chrome)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/zworek/pen/gGbgPL

Am I defining something wrong here or is it purely Chrome's bug?
Even if it is some kind of bug: are there any workarounds?

My Chrome version is 60.0.3112.113 x64

Comment: You do have a syntax error in there - maskUnits are by default objectBoundingBox (% of masked object) - and you're supposed to use maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" - if you want to use pixels. But apart from that, the mask should work. This looks like a regression.

Comment: Filed a version of this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug seems to have been a regression in Chrome 60  - it no longer appears in Chrome 61. (Probably should close the question)